# Prove that n < m + n or that 0 < m in COQ

Tags: coq, proof, inequality

I'm trying to use a lemma for a bigger proof, but I can't find a way to prove one of those two things. Can somebody help me? Here is the proof so far:

```
Lemma less_r : (forall m n p : nat, n + m < p + n + m).

Proof.
 intros.
 apply PeanoNat.Nat.add_lt_mono_r.
 apply PeanoNat.Nat.lt_add_pos_l.
 admit.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your statement cannot be proved because it does not hold.  For instance, if we take `n = m = p = 0`, it implies `0 < 0`, a clear contradiction.

Comment: But there's no way to prove that, except where 0 < 0?

Comment: @RafaelSantos I do not understand what you mean. You need to modify your statement if you want to prove it. One possibility would be to add a precondition about `p`: `forall n m p, 0 < p -> n + m < p + n + m`, which you can easily prove with the `omega` tactic (after adding `Require Import Omega.` to your file). But I don't know if that lemma suits your needs.

Comment: So just so we understand what you want to do, you want to get coq to disprove your claim?